# COM object (.tlb) is in proc or out of proc

Tags: com

We have a C# project that generates .tlb file which is used in C++ code. C++ code accesses the methods of the C# code through this tlb file.
Could anyone please tell if .tlb is in-proc or out-of-proc COM object.
What I have read so far is - dll files are result of in-proc COM and exe files are result of out-of-proc COM.
Please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: The .tlb is just metadata, it doesn't tell you whether your COM "server" runs in-process or out-of-process. An in-process COM server is a .dll loaded in your COM "client" process. An out-of-process COM server is an .exe that lives its own life. Please clarify your question.

Comment: @Vrinda: COM Clients and Servers: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-clients-and-servers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/com/com-clients-and-servers)

Comment: Thanks Simon,
Our C# project generates .dll  and .tlb file but no .exe file. COM Client (C++) uses tlb to access interface and methods of COM Server (C#). Since C# does not generate .exe file, I believe it is in-proc. Please correct me if I am wrong.
My requirement is to know if C++ application is instantiating in-proc COM object or out-of-proc COM object.

Comment: If your COM server is a DLL and you're not hosting it through DllHost (an advanced use case), then your COM server is in-process. Your COM server has a CLSID. Look up HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{Your Server CLSID} in the registry using regedit.exe. Under your CLSID you should see either an InProcServer32 or a LocalServer32 key. The InProcServer32 is the location of the in-process server. The LocalServer32 key is the location of the out-of-process server. Which key you have indicates whether your server is in-process or out-of-process.

Comment: Thanks Joseph, for the information. I checked in Process Explorer (SysInternals), I did not find dllhost.exe under list of DLL for Application. Is this sufficient to verify? 
And I found the server CLSID under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\WOW6432Node\CLSID\  in the registry. And yes it is InprocServer32 under CLSID.
Thanks again  for your kind help.